# Closing table cells in a tabular environment involving multirow and multicolumn

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn, cline

Is there a way to close the cells containing "Field A" and "Field B" only, i.e. with excluding the cell on the top left? Below is a minimal working environment. Thanks for your hints and suggestions.

```
\begin{tabular}{p{0.5cm}c|c|c|c|}
        \cline{2-5}
        & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Type} 
        & $a$ & $b$ & $c$ \\
        \hline\hline
        \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Field A}}} 
        & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Interface 1} 
        & $x_1$ 
        & $y_1$ 
        & $z_1$ \\
        \cline{2-5}
        & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Interface 2} 
        & $x_2$ 
        & $y_2$ 
        & $z_2$ \\
        \cline{2-5}
        & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Interface 3} 
        & $x_3$ 
        & $y_3$ 
        & $z_3$ \\
        \hline\hline
        \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Field B}}} 
        & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Interface 1} 
        & $x_1$ 
        & $y_1$ 
        & $z_1$ \\
        \cline{2-5}
        & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Interface 2} 
        & $x_2$ 
        & $y_2$ 
        & $z_2$ \\
        \cline{2-5}
        & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Interface 3} 
        & $x_3$ 
        & $y_3$ 
        & $z_3$ \\
        \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: (i) please extend your code snippet to complete but small document which we can compile. as it is; (ii) what you mean with " close the cells" write vertical lines on beginning those `multirow` cells?

Comment: You could use `\begin{tabular}{|p{0.5cm}c|c|c|c|}` and `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}` for the empty cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}` as the first cell to have a cell without the vertical line.

I've used

```
\cline{2-5}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}\\[-10pt]\hline
```

to avoid a double horizontal line below the first empty cell.

As Zarko pointed out, `\parbox`es are not needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.5cm}c|c|c|c|}
        \cline{2-5}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{}& \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Type} 
        & $a$ & $b$ & $c$ \\
        \cline{2-5}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{}\\[-10pt]\hline
        \multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Field A}} 
        & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Interface 1} 
        & $x_1$ 
        & $y_1$ 
        & $z_1$ \\
        \cline{2-5}
        & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Interface 2} 
        & $x_2$ 
        & $y_2$ 
        & $z_2$ \\
        \cline{2-5}
        & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Interface 3} 
        & $x_3$ 
        & $y_3$ 
        & $z_3$ \\
        \hline\hline
        \multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Field B}} 
        & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Interface 1} 
        & $x_1$ 
        & $y_1$ 
        & $z_1$ \\
        \cline{2-5}
        & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Interface 2} 
        & $x_2$ 
        & $y_2$ 
        & $z_2$ \\
        \cline{2-5}
        & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Interface 3} 
        & $x_3$ 
        & $y_3$ 
        & $z_3$ \\
        \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is a `\parbox[t]{2mm}{...}` in multi row cell really needed? the very same result you obtain without it :-)

Comment: @Zarko You're right, I'll leave it out